# WPF - ImageBrush with PNG, not respecting alpha-channel

Tags: wpf, imagebrush

I want to use an `ImageBrush` to use in the `Rectangle.Fill`.   The file is a .PNG. It comes out looking like it is sitting on a little gray pad.  The `ImageBrush`  is returned from a converter with something like this:

```
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName));
        ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
        imageBrush.ImageSource = image;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using this in a UserControl and it is either the UserControl or the Grid (that the rectangle sits in that is not transparent. The image\imagebrush is fine.

Comment: Does the Bitmap support transparency (have you called .MakeTransparent on the bitmap or used a ImageFormat with an alpha channel, such as a PNG)? Just a thought.